# Why Collectors.toMap (in JDK8 java.util.stream )not allowed the same key?

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

If we put two k-v pairs into a hashmap with the same key, the second value will override the first one. but if we do this by Collectors.toMap, it will throw en exception with the message:   "Duplicate key".

I know how to fix it, but I want to know why the Collectors design like this.

Comment: `the second value will override the first one` it is valid strategy, but opposite strategy (keep the first entry) is also valid, depending on your needs. To avoid ambiguity designers followed that  way.

Comment: The `put` method was introduced with Java 2, long before lambda expressions in Java. Nowadays we can write `map.merge(key, value, (old, next) -> old)` or `map.merge(key, value, (old, next) -> next)` to express the intended conflict resolution concisely, just like with the `toMap` collector. In Java 2, that option did not exist.

Answer (score 3):

With [`map.put(key, value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-), you haven't lost any information, even if the new entry replaces an existing entry. That is because the method returns the old value, so you only lose information if you don't use the return value, and the method cannot detect if you do, and they cannot force you.

With [`Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-), information will be lost if there is a duplicate key. For safety, it will reject duplicate keys, by throwing an exception. You can accept duplicate keys by providing a `mergeFunction` as a third parameter to explicitly ignore the old value, e.g. using lambda expression `(a,b) -> b` to discard the old value. Here they have the ability to force you to consider the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the collector method: [`toMap​(Function<? super T,​? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T,​? extends U> valueMapper, BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) allows you to specify a merge function to merge values for the same duplicate key.